# Teleporting a rigidbody with OnTriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a weird problem, i want to teleport a `Rigidbody` when i fall of a platform and enter in trigger with a object call `Void`.

here's the code :

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider triggerCollider)
{
    print(triggerCollider.gameObject.name);
    if (triggerCollider.gameObject.name == "void")
    {
        myRigidbody.position = new Vector3(0,10,0);
    }
}
```

`myRigidbody` is the player `Rigidbody`

the print work fine. but moving the `Rigidbody` do not work.

why ? am I missing something ?

Comment: what exactly is `myRigidbody` ? I don't see it defined in the code you've given us

Comment: myRigidbody is a Rigidbody component, I'm assuming, so you should probably use `myRigidbody.transform.position = new Vector3(0,10,0);`

Comment: Also, is the object called "Void" or "void"? String comparisons are CASE SENSITIVE

Comment: Will look into the "Void'/'void" thing, the error may come from here

Comment: @BrandonMiller , you can add a answer the error was the letter! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think You doing the whole thing in a wrong way dude...
first of all  make a reference to your rigidbody
then try to assign a tag to target object and after that, use **OnTriggerEnter** with **compareTag**
you should go as this :

```
  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if (other.CompareTag("yourAssignedTag"))
         myRigidbodyReference.position = new Vector3(0,10,0); 
  }
```

and also you can write a **OnTriggerExit** function to do viseverse thing.
i hope that work for you man!